# Living Style Guide for Webpack?

Tags: css, webpack, frontend

I tend to build front end projects using Webpack so I can use its hot module replacement functionality. I've recently discovered that creating a "living" style guide could be quite useful for a number of different reasons. I've therefore been trying to find one that suits my requirements, but I've not found one that's quite right so far.

My requirements are:

- Allows integration alongside my existing webpack configuration so that I can take advantage of HMR
- Scans SASS files for commented documentation (probably in markdown)
- Scans SASS files for commented markup examples
- Doesn't matter too much, but it would be nice if it's themable in some way

Unless it's just me not configuring it properly (in which case - are there any examples?), I've not been able to get any integrated nicely alongside webpack so far.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: These guys have incorporated sc5 into their workflow and they use webpack.  You can read the full article on this link:  https://www.alleyinteractive.com/news/advanced-techniques-for-the-sc5-styleguide-generator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - in the end, I used the KSS webpack plugin. It seems to work just fine with the only improvement to be made being that is generates physical files when webpack is running HMR. There's a feature request for this to be added on the original KSS node repo, but I imagine this would take some considerable effort.
https://github.com/kss-node/kss-node/issues/311

Comment: "KSS wepack plugin" - this one, right? https://www.npmjs.com/package/kss-webpack-plugin

Comment: Yep - that's the one!